# Parse JSON with Multiple Elements in Python

Tags: python, json

First, I don't have a complete understanding of the terminology on JSON so bear with me.

My school uses a grade book system called PowerSchool. As a side project, I'm trying to made a launchbar action on my Mac so I can quickly check grades. I'm using kimono to grab the grades from PowerSchool. It gives me a JSON output, which Python can grab and output. Currently, I'm trying to be able to list all of the classes. Instead, it lists the first one. Here is an edited version of the JSON I get from kimono. (I edited out personal info and only placed 3 classes in the edit, which may not be correct JSON)

```
name": "Power School",
  "count": 10,
  "frequency": "Every 15 mins",
  "version": 1,
  "newdata": true,
  "lastrunstatus": "success",
  "thisversionstatus": "success",
  "nextrun": "Wed Nov 04 2015 14:02:11 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
  "thisversionrun": "Wed Nov 04 2015 13:47:11 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
  "results": {
    "collection1": [
      {
      {
        "property2": "Class 1",
        "Q1 Grade": {
          "href": "https://powerschool.url",
          "text": "A+\n100"
        },
        "Q2 Grade": {
          "href": "https://powerschool.url",
          "text": "--"
        },
        "Q3 Grade": {
          "href": "https://powerschool.url",
          "text": "--"
        },
        "Q4 Grade": {
          "href": "https://powerschool.url",
          "text": "--"
        },
        "Y1 Grade": {
          "href": "https://powerschool.url",
          "text": "A+\n100"
        },
        "Absences": "0",
        "Tardies": "0",
        "Period": "1-1(A-F)",
        "index": 1,
        "url": "https://powerschool.url/home.html"
      },  
      {
        "property2": "Class 2",
        "Q1 Grade": {
          "href": "https://powerschool.url",
          "text": "A+\n100"
        },
        "Q2 Grade": {
          "href": "https://powerschool.url",
          "text": "--"
        },
        "Q3 Grade": {
          "href": "https://powerschool.url",
          "text": "--"
        },
        "Q4 Grade": {
          "href": "https://powerschool.url",
          "text": "--"
        },
        "Y1 Grade": {
          "href": "https://powerschool.url",
          "text": "A+\n100"
        },
        "Absences": "0",
        "Tardies": "0",
        "Period": "1-1(A-F)",
        "index": 2,
        "url": "https://powerschool.url/home.html"
      },
      {
        "property2": "Class 2",
        "Q1 Grade": {
          "href": "https://powerschool.url",
          "text": "A+\n100"
        },
        "Q2 Grade": {
          "href": "https://powerschool.url",
          "text": "--"
        },
        "Q3 Grade": {
          "href": "https://powerschool.url",
          "text": "--"
        },
        "Q4 Grade": {
          "href": "https://powerschool.url",
          "text": "--"
        },
        "Y1 Grade": {
          "href": "https://powerschool.url",
          "text": "A+\n100"
        },
        "Absences": "0",
        "Tardies": "0",
        "Period": "2-2(A-F)",
        "index": 3,
        "url": "https://powerschool.url/home.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

As for my python script (again, removed the API and Auth keys)

```
import json
import urllib2
request = urllib2.Request("https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/APIKEY", headers={"authorization" : "auth code"})
contents = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
parsed_json = json.loads(contents)
ourResult = parsed_json['results']['collection1'][0]
print ourResult['property2']
```

Running this results in an output of

```
Class 1
```

As where I would expect an output of

```
Class 1
Class 2
Class 3
```

What am I missing? I'm assuming it's something basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just read one item instead of the array. Try this instead:

```
  ourResult = parsed_json['results']['collection1']
  for item in ourResult:
    print item['property2']
```

Answer (score 0):

You put all items of 'collection1' into ourResult.
Create a for loop which iterate each element in ourResult and search for value with key 'property2'